# C# 6: nameof() current property in getter/setter

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, nameof

Is there a way to get the name of the current property in a getter/setter?

Something like this:

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return base.Get<string>(nameof(ThisProperty)); }
    set { base.Set<string>(nameof(ThisProperty), value); }
}
```

`nameof(ThisProperty)` should resolve to "MyProperty".

Comment: `nameof(MyProperty)` should work just fine?

Comment: Why should there? What is the problem with writing `nameof(MyProperty)`?

Comment: This could be useful in a case where the name `MyProperty` might change: then, you have to remember to update `nameof(whatever)`, although the Visual Studio IDE should catch this problem.

Comment: @levelonehuman yes, the IDE should catch this as this was (afaik) one of the main reasons for introducing `nameof`.

Comment: I came across this question when using MVVM's `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ThisProperty))` method and trying to avoid cut and paste issues when generating new properties. I then looked more closely at MVVMLight's method signature and saw they already have an overload for `RaisePropertyChanged()` defined as `public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null);` exactly for this purpose :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It can't be done with `nameof`, but there's an even better way (available since C# 5). You can make the `propertyName` parameter optional and apply the `CallerMemberName` attribute to it:

```
protected void Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    ...
}

protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    ...
}
```

Now if you omit the argument for `propertyName`, the current member name is passed implicitly:

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return base.Get<string>(); } // same as calling Get<string>("MyProperty")
    set { base.Set<string>(value); } // same as calling Set<string>(value, "MyProperty")
}
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thank you sir!

Comment: I beg to differ with your first sentence. As of C# 6, `nameof` will actually do the job: `public string MyProperty
{
    get { return base.Get<string>(nameof(MyProperty)); }
    set { base.Set<string>(nameof(MyProperty), value); }
}`

Comment: @takrl, I think the OP wanted to get the name of the property without having to specify it explicitly. If you use `nameof(MyProperty)`, you still have to write `MyProperty` yourself (admittedly, it's still better than writing it as a string)

Comment: I agree that the use of `[CallerMemberName]` is probably better in this context, but still, the first sentence seems to suggest nameof doesn't work for properties, which is not true.

Comment: Is it not suppose to be : "[CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null" ?

Answer (score -3):

Alternative is to the the MethodBase since a Get and Set are essentially methods.

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4);
    }            
}
```

The substring is there because each name is prefixed with get_ and set_

This returns MyProperty as the result.